# How can I bind a jquery WYSIWYG editor to a contentEditable div

Tags: php, jquery, content-management-system, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I'm developing a cms and I'm currently implementing a way of editing pages content.  At the moment I have a div holding the editable sections which when selected for editing make the div `contentEditable = true`.  This can then be saved via an ajax request. Which all works nicely.

But now I need a method of binding a wysiwyg editor (pref jquery compatible) to the editable div.  Also to complicate things I need the wysiwyg editor toolbar to be in a separate block; which is likely to be a floating toolbar that appears when someone edits a section.

Comment: When you say "binding the editor" do you mean making the editor appear on the page around the editable div?

Comment: You should provide an example, it's easier for others to understand what you are trying.

Comment: Ultimately I would like to have editable sections that when clicked on to edit a floating toolbar will be displayed with wysiwyg controls for that section. The editing and floating toobar are all easy, but it's using the wysiwyg controls on something other than a textarea (like CKEditor and TinyMCE) that's the rub.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.aloha-editor.org/ does pretty much what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd try is to write some functions for drag and drop / resize and so on and live bind them to all children of class `editable`. It would be some work to do, but it's the only solution I see now.